# C# Windows Forms - Assigning the text from a textbox in one variable within xml file

Tags: c#, xml, textbox

I've been working in a Windows Forms Application in C# for run the tasks of my Phing buildfile.

When I click on the button it executes the phing buildfile (runs cmd), saved the console output into a txt file and shows the output in one textbox.

The problem is I have some tasks that need user's input, like SVN commit that needs user to input the commit message.

When I executed the commit task, was showed an empty cmd for the user write the commit message, but the question is not showed, so the user have to guess what's expected to him to write in the console.

I created a input box with the question and the textbox for user answer, but how can I assign the text from the Textbox to the variable within xml file ?
Sorry for some English errors ...

Edit:

In my buildfile I've got this:

```
    <target name="commit" description="Executa Commit">

    <propertyprompt propertyName="commit_message" defaultValue="Actualizado atraves do Phing"
            promptText="Introduza a mensagem do Commit: " />

        <svncommit
        svnpath="${svn_path}"
        workingcopy="${local_dir}"
        message="${commit_message} " />

        <echo msg="Revisao do Commit numero: ${svn.committedrevision}"/>

     </target>
```

So it shows the message "Introduza a mensagem do Commit" and the answer is assigned to commit_message.
In C# I've got an inputbox and I want the text from the textbox to be the value of the "commit_message" in the xml file

Edit for Kamil:

```
textBox1.Clear();
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("phing");
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3";
        startInfo.Arguments = "commit > log.txt";

        string pergunta = inputbox.InputBox("Qual é a mensagem do Commit ?", "Commit", "Mensagem Commit");
        // textBox1.Text = "Escreva o caminho de origem da pasta:";

        Process proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;



        proc.WaitForExit();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\log.txt"))
        {
            textBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Edit number 2 to Kamil:

That way works, but the result is the same of just do this

```
 var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("phing");
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3";
        startInfo.Arguments = "commit ";
        Process proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

my boss told me there's no problem of being like this, just want to add one thing else..
When the console closes I wanna send all the console output to one textbox or just force the console to stay open until I close it

Comment: maybe I am misunderstanding the question but are you asking how to format your XML ? or how to get the code to work with the XML ? I am confused

Comment: I'm asking how to pass the value of the textbox in c# to one variable that is within one xml file.i think I need to use xmldocument or something like that but can't figured it out ...

Comment: There is no such thing as a *variable within a XML file*. Variable is a programming construct. XML file is a structured textual representation of your data. Do you want to a) read from an XML file or b) write to an XML file? What is the XML schema? What are you trying to accomplish? Are you using TortoiseSVN as your client, or plain `svn -commit`? AFAIK, to specify a commit log message, you don't need to create an XML file, but simply a textual file containing data, or you can specify the message in the command itself.

Comment: take a look at this answer see if it helps 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477075/load-xml-data-key-value-pairs-into-data-structure

Comment: Groo I've added some code, can you understand it better now ? Please sorry my english ...

Answer (score 1):

You may use `Process.OutputDataReceived` event to get "the question" (from cmd script I assume).

If you want to enter data to application (cmd?) input - you have to use `Process.StandardInput.WriteLine()` method.

You didn't posted your C# code and I don't know if you are using `Process` to start cmd script or what.

Edit/added later:

```
    textBox1.Clear();
    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("phing");
    startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3";
    // startInfo.Arguments = "commit > log.txt"; // DONT PUT OUTPUT TO FILE
    startInfo.Arguments = "commit"; // we will read output with event

    string pergunta = inputbox.InputBox("Qual é a mensagem do Commit ?", "Commit", "Mensagem Commit");
    // textBox1.Text = "Escreva o caminho de origem da pasta:";

    Process proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;


    // not like this
    // proc.WaitForExit();
    // using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\log.txt"))
    // {
    //    textBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
    // }

    // add handler
    // this will "assign" a function (proc_OutputDataReceived - you can change name)
    // that will be called when proc.OutputDataReceived event will occur
    // for that kind of event - you have to use DataReceivedEventHandler event type
    proc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(proc_OutputDataReceived);


// event handler function (outside function that you pasted)
// this function is assigned to proc.OutputDataReceived event
// by code with "+= new..."
// "sender" is an object in which event occured (when it occurs - "proc" will be available as "sender" here)
// "e" is an object with event parameters (data sent from process and some more)
public void proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    // cast "sender" to Process type
    // "sender" is Process, but it has "object" type, 
    // you have to cast it to use .StandardInput.WriteLine() on "sender"
    Process callerProcess = (Process)sender; 

    MessageBox.Show(e.Data); // this will show text that process sent
    MessageBox.Show(e.Data.ToString()); // you may need to add ToString(), im not sure

    if (e.Data.StartsWith("Revisao do Commit numero"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Process is talking something about Revisao numero"); // :)
        callerProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("Yes! Numero!"); // reply "Yes! Numero!" to process
    }
}
```

If someone more experienced see some mistakes in my code - please fix it if you can. I can't test it right now.

Added later later:

You don't have to use a file and store cmd output. You can read process output directly by using event.

Comment: I've changed "startInfo.Arguments" in code above. I forgot about this. Now it should work.

Comment: gives an error in "proc_OutputDataReceived" "Method must have a return type"

Comment: Fixed (by adding "public void" before function name).

Comment: Well, I think you just have to learn how to use Process.StandardInput and that event... Do some research...