# C# Windows Forms - how to save cmd output into a file but show cmd window at the same time

Tags: c#, winforms, cmd, output

I've got an c# Windows Form Application that runs some tasks of a phing buildfile.
right now  i've got 2 possibilities:

1. On click the button of the xml task it shows the cmd window,
   show the progress of the execution and then closes the cmd (with /k
   I can hold the cmd window open).
2. On click the button the cmd output is saved in one .txt file and
   then I can read the file and show the content in one textbox.(this
   doesn't show the cmd window)

What I want is a mix of this two, because I've got some tasks that show messages to user, and right now if I use the 2nd option it opens an empty cmd window and the users have to guess what's the question.

So what I really want is a way of show the cmd window until the end of execution (like 1st option) but at the same time save the cmd output in a file so I can put the file content in the textbox of my application.

Please sorry for some english mistakes..

Edit for Dour High Arch:

```
           textBox1.Clear();
            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("phing");
            startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3";
            startInfo.Arguments = "commit > log.txt";


            Process proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow =true ;


            proc.WaitForExit();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\log.txt"))
            {
                textBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

With this code the output of the console is showed on the textbox, but the commit task that is executed when I click the button has one question to user, so when that time comes,it opens an empty cmd window that expected  the user commit message but doesn't show the question so user have to guess what's expected !

Other Try:

```
string output = string.Empty;
        string error = string.Empty;
        string path = @"C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\";
        string ffmpegPath = Path.Combine(path, "phing.bat");
        string ffmpegParams = @"commit";

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe");
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\";
        startInfo.Arguments = "/k" + ffmpegPath + " " + ffmpegParams;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;


        Process ffmpeg = new Process();
        ffmpeg.StartInfo = startInfo;
        ffmpeg.Start();

        StreamReader outputReader = ffmpeg.StandardOutput;

        textBox1.Text = outputReader.ReadToEnd();

        ffmpeg.WaitForExit();
        ffmpeg.Close();
```

In this case the cmd doesn't open, so there's no question and there's no answer ! If I set `startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;` then I've got the exception "The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to redirect IO streams".

I've tried more things but the result it's always the same, or I have the cmd window always open but the code isn't passed to the textbox (that's the code I'm using rigth now)

```
 string path = @"C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\";
        string ffmpegPath = Path.Combine(path, "phing.bat");
        string ffmpegParams = @"update";
        Process ffmpeg = new Process();
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\";
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments = "/k" + ffmpegPath +  " " + ffmpegParams;
        ffmpeg.Start();
```

Or I saved the output in one file or stream it directly for the textbox but I don't see the questions.

So anyone knows how to solve it ?

Comment: Was [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18853651/69809) helpful?

Comment: I can't make it work ... Like I said, I can put the output in the textbox or in the cmd window, but I can't have the two working at the same time,  and I need this  ...
All the times I've tried I've always get one exception

Comment: If you get an exception you need to show us the exception and the code that is throwing it.

Comment: all the code in my edit, sorry for the later answer

Answer (score 0):

Use the 1st option and capture the cmd output by redirecting the output to a file.

A complete example is shown [here](http://csharptest.net/532/using-processstart-to-capture-console-output/).

Comment: Thanks Caroline. I'm new in C# (well, in programming), so I adapted that code to my code, but I don't figured how do I call the function, can you give me examples of the expected arguments ?